# vary a xaml template by type

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, datatemplate

Below is a piece of a DataTemplate that defines a strip if commands (buttons with images) for contacting clients. Currently defined for telephone contacts, there are several more commands, so I want to reuse this for other types of contact methods (email, etc.)

The way it and the view models behind it are designed, there are only two things that need to vary to do this:

1. The image and tool tip for the ContactCommand button
2. The entire last button

It seems the most reusable approach would be to have the entire button be itself a DataTemplate with a DataType defined like at the bottom of this post, but I am not grokking how the original DataTemplate would consume this. I've also never used a DataTemplateSelector although that sounds promising.

What is the best approach? How would the code look?

Cheers,
Berryl

## current DataTemplate

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="TelecomNumbersControlCommands">

    <DataTemplate.Resources>

        <!-- Image Style -->
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="Height" Value="16" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="16" />
        </Style>

    </DataTemplate.Resources>

    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="5,0,5,0">

        <Button Command="{Binding AddCommand}" >
            <Image Source="{resx:Resx Key=Img_Simplicio_Add, ResxName=Presentation.Resources.MasterDetail}" />
            <Button.ToolTip>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <resx:Resx Key="Subject_AddNew_ToolTip" BindingPath="SubjectVm.DisplayName" ResxName="Presentation.Resources.MasterDetail"/>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </Button.ToolTip>
        </Button>

        <Button Command="{Binding ContactCommand}" >
            <Image Source="{resx:Resx Key=Img_Telephone, ResxName=Smack.Parties.Presentation.Resources.PartyDetailView}" />
            <Button.ToolTip>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <resx:Resx Key="ContactCommand_Telephone_Tooltip" BindingPath="SelectedVm" ResxName="Smack.Parties.Presentation.Resources.PartyDetailView"/>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </Button.ToolTip>
        </Button>

        </Button>

        <Button Command="{Binding SetDefaultAreaCodeCommand}" >
            <Image Source="{resx:Resx Img_Widget, ResxName=Presentation.Resources.MasterDetail}" />
            <Button.ToolTip>
                <TextBlock>
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <resx:Resx Key="Subject_Settings" BindingPath="SubjectVm.DisplayName" ResxName="Presentation.Resources.MasterDetail"/>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
            </Button.ToolTip>
        </Button>

        ...

    </StackPanel>

</DataTemplate>
```

## For RACHEL

## Revised Button w/ implicit data templates

```
<Button Command="{Binding ContactCommand}" >
    <Button.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type CmTypes:TelecomNumberPcmShellVm}">
            <Image Source="{resx:Resx Key=Img_Telephone, ResxName=Presentation.Resources.PartyDetailView}" >
                <Image.ToolTip>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <resx:Resx 
                                Key="ContactCommand_Telephone_Tooltip" 
                                BindingPath="SelectedVm" ResxName="Presentation.Resources.PartyDetailView"/>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Image.ToolTip>
            </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Button.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type CmTypes:EmailPcmShellVm}">
            <Image Source="{resx:Resx Key=Img_Email, ResxName=Presentation.Resources.PartyDetailView}" >
                <Image.ToolTip>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <resx:Resx 
                                Key="ContactCommand_Email_Tooltip" 
                                BindingPath="SelectedVm" ResxName="Presentation.Resources.PartyDetailView"/>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Image.ToolTip>
            </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
</Button>

Object Model

public class PcmShellVm<TCm> : SatelliteViewModel<Party, HashSet<PartyContactMechanism>> 
    where TCm : ContactMechanism
{
    // commands...
}

public class TelephoneNumberPcmShellVm : PcmShellVm<Telephone>
{
    ...
}

public class EmailPcmShellVm : PcmShellVm<Email>
{
    ...
}
```

## Object model

```
public class PcmShellVm<TCm> : SatelliteViewModel<Party, HashSet<PartyContactMechanism>> 
    where TCm : ContactMechanism
{
    // commands...
}

public class TelephoneNumberPcmShellVm : PcmShellVm<Telephone>
{
    ...
}

public class EmailPcmShellVm : PcmShellVm<Email>
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Your `DataTemplate` in your last code block doesn't work because you are putting the `DataTemplate` into `Button.Content`. If you put it in `<Button.Resources>`, it will probably work providing `Button.Content` is of type `CmTypes:TelecomNumberPcmShellVm`.

Comment: @Rachel. Hi Rachel - I tried that and the error shifts to 'Button.ToolTip' [attachable property 'ToolTip' was not found in type 'Button']. Does that make sense to you?

Comment: @Rachel. Why not turn your comment into an answer? I'm sure you are pretty close to one as is. Cheers

Comment: Sure, I posted that as an answer, along with an answer about the `ToolTip`. I didn't post it originally as an answer because I wasn't sure if it answered your question or not :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `DataTemplate` in your last code block doesn't work because you are putting the `DataTemplate` into `Button.Content`. If you put it in `<Button.Resources>`, it should work providing `Button.Content` is of type `CmTypes:TelecomNumberPcmShellVm`

In addition, you need to switch to an `Image.ToolTip` to add a tooltip to the Image, as `Button.ToolTip` is not a valid property for your `DataTemplate`

```
<Button Command="{Binding ContactCommand}">
    <Button.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type CmTypes:TelecomNumberPcmShellVm}">
            <Image Source="{resx:Resx Key=Img_Telephone, ResxName=Presentation.Resources.PartyDetailView}">
                <Image.ToolTip>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock.Text>
                            <resx:Resx Key="ContactCommand_Telephone_Tooltip" 
                                       BindingPath="SelectedVm" 
                                       ResxName="Presentation.Resources.PartyDetailView"/>
                        </TextBlock.Text>
                    </TextBlock>
                </Image.ToolTip>
            </Image>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

If you actually do want to set `Button.ToolTip` instead of `Image.ToolTip`, then you will probably need to set it in a `DataTrigger` in `Button.Style`. Usually for this kind of scenario I have a converter that returns `typeof(value)`, so my `DataTrigger` looks something like this:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ObjectToTypeConverter}}" 
             Value="{x:Type CmTypes:TelecomNumberPcmShellVm}">
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" ... />
</DataTrigger>
```

This could also be used to set the `Button.ContentTemplate` instead of using implicit data templates as shown above.

Comment: So it compiles but does not work; meaning it does not appear at all. Since there is no data binding error (and the bound commands work), am guessing this suggests its not finding the type for some reason. Please see revisions at end of posting!

Comment: I *think* I like the converter solution in this case, since it I actually can reuse that an make the xaml leaner; BUT am not positive I understand how to code it. It also seems like a DataTemplateSelector approach might work, but I don't know how to code that either! So I'm going to ask a variation of this as
a separate question - this way this post won't get more convoluted than it already is, and you can have an opportunity to rack up some more points, which you obviously need :--)

Comment: [the other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353348/xaml-polymorphism). Cheers

Comment: @Berryl The `Button.Content` in your modified XAML is still set to a `DataTemplate`. If `Button.Content` is set to an object of type `TelecomNumberPcmShellVm` (such as `Content="{Binding SomeTelecomNumberProperty}"`), it will use the `DataTemplate` defined in `Button.Resources` to draw that item.

Comment: Yes, just putting 'Content = {Binding}' made that work. Love it if yoou could to [look at [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/). Cheers

Comment: @Berryl Your link doesn't work, but I'm assuming you mean [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13353348/302677). I usually don't use `DataTemplateSelectors` because they don't get re-evaluated when changes occur the way DataTriggers do, and I like to see the logic for selecting a template in the XAML instead of having it hidden in another code file. I almost always use implicit DataTemplates to tell WPF how to render different object types, and the only time I've used a `DataTemplateSelector` was when I was working with Silverlight a while ago, before it supported implicit DataTemplates