# UserControl update image based on datatype

Tags: wpf, image, mvvm, resourcedictionary

I have a program that displays either customer, company or employee info.  I would like to display an icon next to this image with the icon changing based on the type of info I am displaying (customer, company or employee).

I have the following setup in my resource dictionary to specify the images:

```
<ImageSource x:Key="CompanyIcon">../Images/companies_32.png</ImageSource>
<ImageSource x:Key="EmployeeIcon">../Images/employee_32.png</ImageSource>
<ImageSource x:Key="CustomerIcon">../Images/customer_32.png</ImageSource>
```

In my viewmodel I would like to assign the image based on what data type I am working with.  For instance if I am viewing a company's info (a DBContext of type 'Company' using EF 4.5) I want to set the image to that of 'CompanyIcon'.

How would I assign the image with the viewmodel (and change it as I change between a 'Company', 'Employee' or 'Customer' DBContext type) and then bind this image to a placeholder in the view (it will be displayed within a grid column).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a `DataTrigger` that sets the `Image.Source` based on the object type, and use a Converter that returns the `typeof(value)` for getting the type

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
    <!-- Default Value -->
    <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource CompanyIcon}" />

    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ObjectToTypeConverter}}" 
                     Value="{x:Type local:Employee}">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource EmployeeIcon}" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ObjectToTypeConverter}}" 
                     Value="{x:Type local:Customer}">
            <Setter Property="Source" Value="{StaticResource CustomerIcon}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The converter I usually use just looks like this:

```
public class ObjectToTypeConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value == null)
            return null;

        return value.GetType();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  Can you tell me if the Style is stored in the ResourceDictionary?  And then how would I implement this style inside a grid layout?

Comment: @BrianKE The Style can be placed in any `<FrameworkElement.Resources>` tag in the XAML, such as `<UserControl.Resources>` or `<Window.Resources>`, or in a `ResourceDictionary`, then you would have to make your `Image` apply the style, such as `<Image Style="{DynamicResource MyImageStyle}">`

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to have a string property in the VM pointing to the image location (don't know if it's the best approach, but it worked quite well for me):

```
private string _imageSource;
public string ImageSource 
{
   get
   {
     return _imageSource;
   }
   set
   {
      _imageSource = value;
      NotifyPropertyChanged(() => ImageSource);
   }

}

public void SetImage()
{
    If (customer)
        ImageSource = "../Images/companies_32.png";
    ...
}
```

in XAML:

```
<Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}" .../>
```

Comment: The problem with doing this in the vm is that you are needlessly blurring the separation of concerns, which should only be done as a last resort. Disrespecting the separation of concerns will lead to bloated and brittle view models. The image display is a View concern that, in this case, is easily handled by the View once you know how. Cheers

Comment: @Berryl that's true. How would you recommend to handle this instead?

Comment: This particular situation where you need to vary the image for one control by type? I like Rachel's solution presented here actually. [Here is another](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344259/vary-a-xaml-template-by-type/13350720#13350720) example of how a more complicated switching by type rendering could be implemented in with DataTemplates and implicit data typing.

Comment: And FWIW I used to try and jam stuff like this in to my view models too! Seemed like a good idea until I found my view model(s) were needlessly bloated and brittle...